# Adaptors as inner classes of activities, or stand alone classes?

Tags: android, networking, user-interface, coding-style

I'm looking to establish some "best practices" for Android, with regards to code reuse, ease of programming/understanding, performance and memory. So, you know, just good code all around.

It seems like a lot of the Android documentation and object design pushes you towards having lots of inner classes. AsyncTask likes to load data right into Views. Adaptors like to have access to the LayoutInflator.

From a code reuse viewpoint, it would be nice to build a few adaptors or AsyncTasks that solve your problems, and reuse them as needed. This means passing around your context though, which feels dirty and can lead to memory pitfalls if not done carefully. The other option is to bake all the AsyncTasks and Adaptors that an activity needs directly into the Activity. This makes it hard to reuse code, but you can see where things are going easily and since you're using the context directly it's harder to hold onto things forever.

I'm also concerned about writing code that will look familiar to programmers we might hire in the future.

What are the coding standards for Android? What is the "best design" for an application which needs to load nearly all of it's data from the web, have a UI that works on phones and tablets (with different activities in each), and be easy to work with and extend for years to come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [this](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html)  on How to code in android.

And you can use inner class or make a seprate class according to your need. For example when all data is being loaded from web in json format i always use a seprate class with a static method which will return the `jsonObject` and then i can call this method anywhere in my app and extract data from it.
Also i use single inner class of `asyncTask` perfoming different task in my activity like seraching and loading data in `listview`, loading data on user prefrences change.and so on.
In custom adapter i always prefer different class for them. It'll really make easy to work with them. 
Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I've asked this before, and this is the way I do it.

If I'm going to use the adapter many times, I place all of my adapters into a package called "com.myapp.adapters" As for the AsyncTask, I always use asynctasks as part of activities.

If you only have a short adapter that does a little bit of work in an activity, there's no need to create a separate class file for it. Just stick it into the activity.